# Solutions of $\phi(x)=n$ for a given n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I need to prove for a given n, if $\phi(x)=n$ has a solution for x, it always has another?

We know $\phi(2)=\phi(1)=1$ and can easily prove that n must be even for x>2.

So, n can be of the form $2^a.q$ where a>0 , odd q are natural numbers.

Comment: I see no question mark anywhere...

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee I need to contact with you regarding some discussion. Can you please mail me your contact id to my email id anjandebnath@rocketmail.com ?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath, see my profile here.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I apologize but did you provide any link in "here" ? I opened your math.stackexchange profile but could not get your contact id.

Comment: @AnjanDebnath, lab.bhattacharjee@gmail.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to prove that, you're in big trouble. It's [Carmichael's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function_conjecture), and it's wide open.

Comment: Thanks for the update, actually the problem was mentioned in his "The theory of numbers"

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd then $\phi(n)=\phi(2n)$.