# Find solutions of $\phi{(x)} = n$.

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

> Given a positive integer $n$. Find all $x$ such that $\phi{(x)} = n$.

This kind of questions exists here. Such as [Solutions of $\phi(x)=n$ for a given n.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181627/solutions-of-phix-n-for-a-given-n)
But my question is different. I am looking for an approach to find all solution $x$. Is there any algorithm/method how to do this?
I also managed to find this OEIS sequence [A032447](https://oeis.org/A032447). But that doesn't help me.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate as well.

Comment: There should be an anwer mentioning how to bound the possible numbers. I do not remember exactly where, but I remember such a bound.